# Чистое ООП на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

столкнулся с такой проблемой нужно при каждом вызове конструктора **init** что бы переменная self.name добавлялась в один общий список. Реализовал с помощью for но не работает, не могу понять почему. 2 проблема. Считается ли правильным использование так много строчек кода с созданием новых объектов и как этот код можно уменьшить

```
class I_am:
    def __init__(self , money , carrying):
        self.money = money
        self.carrying = carrying

    def money_down(self):
        pass

class Town:

    def __init__(self , name , distance):
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance
        random_town_spisok = []

        for town in self.name:
            random_town_spisok.append(self.name)
            print(random_town_spisok)



class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, quality, price):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.quality = quality
        self.price = price
        self.spisok = []

        # for Product in self.name:
        #     self.spisok.append(self.name)
        #     print(self.spisok)

# Товар = деньги и грузоподъёмность
    def product_money(self, money, carrying):
        # Проверка на количество денег
        if money.money >= self.price:
            money.money = money.money - self.price
            print(f"Мы купили {self.name} за {self.price} биткоинов, на счету осталось {money.money} биткоинов!")
        else:
            print(f"Кошелек пуст")
            exit()

        #Проверка на грузоподъёмность
        if carrying.carrying >= self.weight:
            carrying.carrying = carrying.carrying - self.weight
        else:
            print(f"Машина загружена")
            exit()


Info = I_am(100, 70)


Towm_one = Town('Moskov', 100)
Towm_two = Town('Almaty', 60)
Towm_tree = Town('Talgar', 50)
Towm_four = Town('Taraz', 80)
Towm_five = Town('Rostov', 90)



Product_one = Product('Мясо', 10, 1, 10)
Product_two = Product('Сухофрукты', 2, 1, 8)
Product_tree = Product('Зерно', 7, 1, 10)
Product_four = Product('Мука', 8, 1, 10)
Product_five = Product('Ткань', 20, 1, 16)
Product_six = Product('Краска', 20, 1, 7)

Product_one.product_money(Info, Info)
Product_two.product_money(Info, Info)
Product_tree.product_money(Info, Info )
Product_four.product_money(Info , Info)
Product_five.product_money(Info, Info)
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вообще здесь цикл `for town in self.name`? Он разобьёт название города на буквы и затем `random_town_spisok.append(self.name)` в цикле добавит название города в список столько раз, сколько букв в этом названии. Ну и `random_town_spisok` у вас локальная переменная, так что она нигде не сохранится после завершения функции `__init__()`.
По второму вопросу - используйте циклы и списки.

```
class I_am:
    def __init__(self , money , carrying):
        self.money = money
        self.carrying = carrying

    def money_down(self):
        pass

class Town:
    random_town_spisok = []

    def __init__(self , name , distance):
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance

        Town.random_town_spisok.append(self.name)
        print(Town.random_town_spisok)



class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, quality, price):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.quality = quality
        self.price = price
        self.spisok = []

        # for Product in self.name:
        #     self.spisok.append(self.name)
        #     print(self.spisok)

# Товар = деньги и грузоподъёмность
    def product_money(self, money, carrying):
        # Проверка на количество денег
        if money.money >= self.price:
            money.money = money.money - self.price
            print(f"Мы купили {self.name} за {self.price} биткоинов, на счету осталось {money.money} биткоинов!")
        else:
            print(f"Кошелек пуст")
            exit()

        #Проверка на грузоподъёмность
        if carrying.carrying >= self.weight:
            carrying.carrying = carrying.carrying - self.weight
        else:
            print(f"Машина загружена")
            exit()


info = I_am(100, 70)

towns = [Town(*args) for args in (('Moskov', 100),
                                  ('Almaty',  60),
                                  ('Talgar',  50),
                                  ('Taraz' ,  80),
                                  ('Rostov',  90)
                                 )]
products = [Product(*args) for args in (('Мясо'      , 10, 1, 10),
                                        ('Сухофрукты',  2, 1,  8),
                                        ('Зерно'     ,  7, 1, 10),
                                        ('Мука'      ,  8, 1, 10),
                                        ('Ткань'     , 20, 1, 16),
                                        ('Краска'    , 20, 1,  7)
                                       )]
for prod in products:
    prod.product_money(info, info)
```